# How to add in my plugin a third vendor Git project with composer.json

Tags: composer, namespace

I need to use this [Git project](https://github.com/frozensheep/rightmoveADF) in my plugin.

First I drop source code in a folder, and load it with

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/Frozensheep/RightmoveADF/RightmoveADF.php';
```

But there is a problem, because although apparently one Class (for instance `GetBranchPropertyList`) is loaded by the namespace use:

```
    //
    use Frozensheep\RightmoveADF\Request\GetBranchPropertyList;
    //
```

I get an error when invoke the class:

```
   //
   return new GetBranchPropertyList();
   //

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Frozensheep\RightmoveADF\Request\GetBranchPropertyList' not found
```

The project includes a composer.json, which I think is what I need to install and configure, but I have no idea how to use it.

Can someone explain me step by step how to proceed with **composer.json** config?

Answer (score 1):

Composer generates the autoloader for you. Thus, you don't need to require a specific file from vendor packages. All you need to do is require the composer autoloader:

Change `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/Frozensheep/RightmoveADF/RightmoveADF.php';`
 to 
`require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'vendor/autoload.php';`

In some cases, classes still not be found. Re-generate the composer autoloader by `$ composer dump-autoload`.

Usually, you should not mess with the `vendor` directory. If you did, I suggest you remove the `vendor` directory and re-install packages by `$ rm -dr vendor/` and `$ composer install`